# RAML api-console is not loading the api.raml file

Tags: api, angularjs-directive, raml

I am trying to get the RAML api-console working like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/api-console-light-theme.css" type="text/css"/>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="ramlConsoleApp" ng-cloak>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/api-console-vendor.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="api-console.js"></script>

    <div style="overflow:auto;position:relative;">
      <raml-console src="api.raml"></raml-console>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

It seems like the part `src="api.raml"` is not doing anything.

All other parts work fine. For instance, adding the attribute `disable-theme-switcher` removes the "switch theme" button from the page.

There are no errors in the console and the "network" tab in the Chrome developer tool does not show a failed download. So it seems the application is not even trying to load the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `<raml-console-loader src="api.raml"></raml-console-loader>` instead of `<raml-console src="api.raml"></raml-console>`. Note that additional directives such as `disable-theme-switcher` are not working in this new tag as of the current state of the `raml-1.0` branch. You can see relevant issues [#278](https://github.com/mulesoft/api-console/pull/278), [#284](https://github.com/mulesoft/api-console/issues/284), and [286](https://github.com/mulesoft/api-console/pull/286).

Comment: Thx. Does that work with raml 0.8 as well? I'm using 0.8 because 1.0 seems not yet supported by abao.

Comment: @HendrikJan I did not test with 0.8. In fact 1.0 was supported for quite sometime in a separate branch names `raml-1.0`. However, it seems like that branch is now merged in the `master`. Please try downloading the latest master branch.